# How to hide #href in url in that jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this script (in combination with bootstrap) to make an animated scroll to the sections of a single page site.
I would like to hide the appearance of the href in the address bar.

**HTML NAV**

```
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="current"><a href="#body">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

**jQuery**

```
if (typeof Object.create !== "function") {
    Object.create = function(e) {
        function t() {}
        t.prototype = e;
        return new t
    }
}(function(e, t, n, r) {
    "use strict";
    var i = {
        init: function(n, r) {
            this.options = e.extend({}, e.fn.singlePageNav.defaults, n);
            this.container = r;
            this.$container = e(r);
            this.$links = this.$container.find("a");
            if (this.options.filter !== "") {
                this.$links = this.$links.filter(this.options.filter)
            }
            this.$window = e(t);
            this.$htmlbody = e("html, body");
            this.$links.on("click.singlePageNav", e.proxy(this.handleClick, this));
            this.didScroll = false;
            this.checkPosition();
            this.setTimer()
        },
        handleClick: function(t) {
            var n = this,
                r = t.currentTarget,
                i = e(r.hash);
            t.preventDefault();
            if (i.length) {
                n.clearTimer();
                if (typeof n.options.beforeStart === "function") {
                    n.options.beforeStart()
                }
                n.setActiveLink(r.hash);
                n.scrollTo(i, function() {
                    if (n.options.updateHash && history.pushState) {
                        history.pushState(null, null, r.hash)
                    }
                    n.setTimer();
                    if (typeof n.options.onComplete === "function") {
                        n.options.onComplete()
                    }
                })
            }
        },
        scrollTo: function(e, t) {
            var n = this;
            var r = n.getCoords(e).top;
            var i = false;
            n.$htmlbody.stop().animate({
                scrollTop: r
            }, {
                duration: n.options.speed,
                easing: n.options.easing,
                complete: function() {
                    if (typeof t === "function" && !i) {
                        t()
                    }
                    i = true
                }
            })
        },
        setTimer: function() {
            var e = this;
            e.$window.on("scroll.singlePageNav", function() {
                e.didScroll = true
            });
            e.timer = setInterval(function() {
                if (e.didScroll) {
                    e.didScroll = false;
                    e.checkPosition()
                }
            }, 250)
        },
        clearTimer: function() {
            clearInterval(this.timer);
            this.$window.off("scroll.singlePageNav");
            this.didScroll = false
        },
        checkPosition: function() {
            var e = this.$window.scrollTop();
            var t = this.getCurrentSection(e);
            this.setActiveLink(t)
        },
        getCoords: function(e) {
            return {
                top: Math.round(e.offset().top) - this.options.offset
            }
        },
        setActiveLink: function(e) {
            var t = this.$container.find("a[href$='" + e + "']");
            if (!t.hasClass(this.options.currentClass)) {
                this.$links.removeClass(this.options.currentClass);
                t.addClass(this.options.currentClass)
            }
        },
        getCurrentSection: function(t) {
            var n, r, i, s;
            for (n = 0; n < this.$links.length; n++) {
                r = this.$links[n].hash;
                if (e(r).length) {
                    i = this.getCoords(e(r));
                    if (t >= i.top - this.options.threshold) {
                        s = r
                    }
                }
            }
            return s || this.$links[0].hash
        }
    };
    e.fn.singlePageNav = function(e) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var t = Object.create(i);
            t.init(e, this)
        })
    };
    e.fn.singlePageNav.defaults = {
        offset: 0,
        threshold: 120,
        speed: 400,
        currentClass: "current",
        easing: "swing",
        updateHash: false,
        filter: "",
        onComplete: false,
        beforeStart: false
    }
})(jQuery, window, document)
```

I would like to get the same result as this script (but with the animation):

```
 $('a').each(function(){  
 $(this).attr('onclick','window.location.href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'"');
 $(this).attr('href','#');
 });
```

is it possible to get what I want?

Comment: than use a button with a data attribute I am not sure what the big deal with the address bar with the hash is. Why don't you use proper names for your sections and than people could link to those sections in bookmarks and stuff.

Comment: it is a single page site... i don't need href in url

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want as you are already setting window.location.href onClick of a tag. Can you please elaborate and also create a fiddle?

Comment: I have single page apps that are linkable. ;) So use a button like I said `<button data-id="1">foo</button>` Read the data attribute, style the button to look like text

Comment: @SmitRaval If i use window.location.href onClick i bypass animated scroll and reach directly the section

Comment: @epascarello i don't need that! I need to use scroll animation that is provided by jquery script

Comment: So change the script to look for a button and read the data attribute.... or remove the href and add a data attribute and read that instead of the href.

Comment: @epascarello if i use button, as you say, after i don't know how to use the scroll animation...I would have the same problem. I think that the solution is to change setActiveLink with right code... but i don't know how